# php zend framework form display group

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

Im using zend form and display group with code below :

```
$profile=new Zend_Form_Element_Select('profile');
$profile->setLabel('name of profile');
foreach ($Current_User_Profile['profiles'][0] as $pro)
    $profile->addMultiOption($pro,$pro);
$profile->setValue($Model_Port_Speed->Current_User_Profile($Current_User_Profile['my_user_id'], $Current_User_Profile['username']));

$Form_User_Settings->addDisplayGroup(array($profile), 'profile_change',array ('legend' => 'profile name here' ));
$profile_change = $Form_User_Settings->getDisplayGroup('profile_change');
$profile_change->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        'Fieldset',
        array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'div','style'=>'width:100%;float:right;'))
));
```

I get this error :

> No valid elements specified for display group

where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is a error in the definition of elements. This error indicates there are no elements in your display group that are set by you:

```
        $Form_User_Settings->addDisplayGroup(array($profile), 'profile_change',array ('legend' => 'profile name here' ));
```

Should be:

```
        $Form_User_Settings->addDisplayGroup(array('profile'), 'profile_change',array ('legend' => 'profile name here' ));
```

Comment: NO! I tested this code.did not work. The point is that, code runs on my own computer with out error,but on server the error occurs!Actully in final sub version of zend framework 1, array('profile') and array($profile) are the same!

Comment: Code is 100% correct :) Are you sure the code and further config on the server is exactly the same (no cached results, forgotten upload etc) and are you sure the error is the same?

Comment: Just a thought; are there any values in your foreach on the server (so there is at least one record in the select list)?